# Create DataFrame containing dicts with values according to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe

```
a = pd.DataFrame([2,4,3,6])
```

and want to create a corresponding second dataframe containig dicts with the same numeric entries as the first dataframe:

```
                0
0  {'example': 2}
1  {'example': 4}
2  {'example': 3}
3  {'example': 6}
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work (b doesn't change at all with the second operation):

```
b = pd.DataFrame([[{'example':0}]] * 4)
b.loc[:][0]['example'] = a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new df with a list comprehension for which each element is a list containing the dict.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[{'example': x}] for x in a.iloc[:, 0]])
```

Output

```
                0
0  {'example': 2}
1  {'example': 4}
2  {'example': 3}
3  {'example': 6}
```